# Jpa @PersistenceUnit ignores transaction_new

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

Is Application managed persistence context aware of 
*@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)* 
 annotation? Or you have to instantiate a new Entity Manager inside that method for DB changes to be done in a new transaction?

I have method that is annotated with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW). When used with @PersistenceContext it works fine, but when used with @PersistenceUnit, there is no data commit at the end of the method.

We have implemented multitenancy with JPA by creating Entity manager factory and later instantiating EM the following way:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MeveoAdminMultiTenant", props);

...
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return (EntityManager) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] { EntityManager.class }, (proxy, method, args) -> {
            currentEntityManager.joinTransaction();
            return method.invoke(currentEntityManager, args);
    });
```

But it completely ignores transaction_new annotation even though it is container manager transaction. It joins JTA transaction, so no additional transaction begin/commit/rollback is needed.

EM is produced with @RequestScoped.

What is a proper way for application managed EM to respect transaction_new annotation? Do I need to obtain a different EM in that method?

Running Wildfly 10.1-Final with Hibernate 5.0.10

Thanks